# Show EmguCV Image in WPF form

Tags: c#, wpf, image, emgucv

I am building a program that needs to capture the image from a webam and show it to the user. I am using EmguCV to capture the image from the webcam and make some computer vision processing and then i need to show the image to the user. I have the image in the EmguCV's format (`Image<Bgr, byte>`)

The forms are WPF, so I just have an `Image` item on the form showing the result.

I guess I can save the image to the hard drive and make the form to load it again, but I dont think this is a good solution since I need to show the captured images in "real time".

How can I load the EmguCV image into the form image container?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look [here](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/WPF_in_CSharp) to convert to a `BitmapSource` which you can then bind to an `Image` control.